# Node.js - problemas com async/await em um setInterval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Estou desenvolvendo um bot para monitorar uma aplicação. A função areaDocenteMonitor.start() faz apenas uma requisição e retorna o status. Caso o status seja diferente de 200 é disparado um e-mail com o erro.

A função é executada em determinado tempo utilizando o setInterval().

Acontece que ele não está respeitando o await da função que dispara o e-mail e está se atropelando.

```
function start(time) {
  setInterval(async () => {
    const { status, statusText } = await areaDocenteMonitor.start();

    console.log(status, statusText);
    console.log(`${new Date()}\n`);

    if (status !== 200) {
      await mail.sendMail(
        template({
          title: 'Perda de conexão Área Docente',
          err: `${status} - ${statusText}`,
        })
      );
    }
  }, time);
}
```

Aqui vai um exemplo do log:

```
502 Bad Gateway
Tue Mar 24 2020 19:37:43 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)

502 Bad Gateway
Tue Mar 24 2020 19:37:43 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)

502 Bad Gateway
Tue Mar 24 2020 19:37:44 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)

502 Bad Gateway
Tue Mar 24 2020 19:37:46 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)

Message sent: <c61724e6-a614-8b14-d9a8-e9740b140327@univem.edu.br>
502 Bad Gateway
Tue Mar 24 2020 19:37:47 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)

Message sent: <681b01f2-fc7b-522b-ff21-ae02fe9c5562@univem.edu.br>
502 Bad Gateway
Tue Mar 24 2020 19:37:47 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)

Message sent: <14241a63-a8a2-db96-2a1b-bf11945d3532@univem.edu.br>
Message sent: <bba9f052-22e4-b78f-f247-959417de5fad@univem.edu.br>
502 Bad Gateway
Tue Mar 24 2020 19:37:48 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)
```

Eu queria que ele chamasse o areaDocenteMonitor.start() apenas depois de ter finalizado o disparo de e-mail.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Ou se existe outra forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Qual o tempo que está sendo enviado para o setInterval?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Fiz um exemplo espero que o ajude, assimile sua função desta mesma forma que provavelmente resolvera seu problema

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
 
app.get('/teste', function (req, res) {
  console.log('entrou na rota')
  //Função exemplo
  function areaDocenteMonitor(){
  console.log('<<<<< 1- areaDocenteMonitor >>>>>');
  return '500';
  }
  //Email exemplo
  function mail(){
 console.log('2 - Enviando email >>>>> \n');
  
  }
  
  function start(time) {
  setInterval(async() => {
    const x = await areaDocenteMonitor();

    console.log(x,`${new Date()}\n`);
   
    if (x !== '200') {
       const y = await mail();
    }
  }, time);
}

start(2000);

});
 
app.listen(3000, function (){
 console.log('Server Rodando')
});
```